# Why is my Ajax callback not returning anything?

Tags: 8, ajax, webforms

I'm implementing an ajax callback function whats the issue with my code not returning anything.  I'm new to backend

```
  <?php
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\Query\QueryFactory;

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ReplaceCommand;

/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function hook_form_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_submission_go_to_csv_import_add_form') {
    // Choose for "Featured Type" field "N/A" value by default.
    $form['elements']['name']= [
      '#type' => textfield,
      '#title' => 'sammy',
      '#ajax' => [
                'callback' => '::some_ajax_sample',
                'wrapper' => 'edit-name',
                'event' => 'keyup',
                'progress' => [
                  'type' => 'throbber',
                  'message' => 'loading.....',
                ]
              ],
            ];


  }
}

function some_ajax_sample(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $response = new Response($form['elements']['name']['#title'] = 'Test');
    return $response;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

there are a few things that could go wrong with this. Ajax callbacks can be a really hard thing to do and often requires a bit of trail and error. Hope this helps.

First of all, when your ajax callback function should not contain the "**::**".
This is only used when you are programming inside a Class, right now you're in a `.module`.
So you can change to.

```
'callback' => 'some_ajax_sample'
```

Furthermore you should check with a breakpoint if you even get inside the function. This should be resolved when removing the **::**.

Second thing you should do is add the wrapper div to your element.
You can do it like this:

```
$form['elements']['name']= [
  '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-name">'
  '#suffix' => '</div>'
  '#type' => textfield,
  '#title' => 'sammy',
  '#ajax' => [
            'callback' => 'some_ajax_sample',
            'wrapper' => 'edit-name',
            'event' => 'keyup',
            'progress' => [
              'type' => 'throbber',
              'message' => 'loading.....',
            ]
          ],
        ];
}
```

When you added the wrapper, Drupal knows which element should be replaced and update.

Last thing you can try is to remove the response and to just return the `$form['elements']['name']`.

Hope this helps.